# PowerBI for AD guest users

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI report I want to share with a Guest user of my AD.
I have provided a PowerBI license for this guest user and created a tab in a Teams channel. Unfortunately, he is not able to open the PowerBI report, he got a "The content isn't available".

What is the issue? Is it possible to assign a license to a guest user?

Comment: Have you shared the workspace with him? Please give more info on your problem, there is not much..

Comment: The workspace is an Office365 group (a Microsoft Teams), so the guest user is already a member of the team.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. If you want the guest user to just consume the report, then you can share the dashboard with their external email address and they get an email invitation as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards?#share-a-dashboard-or-report).

[image: share dashboard with external user]

2. If you want the guest user to author the report, then the user needs to sign in specifically to your Power BI tenant. This [article](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-ad-b2b-guest-users-can-now-edit-and-manage-content-in-power-bi-to-collaborate-better-across-organizations/) and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b?) walk through the steps to find your tenant URL.

[image: allow guest to edit]